# iframe GET url variable

Tags: php, iframe, get

I'm trying to give the users of my website the option to externally embed an html5 player , and in order to do that I thought of putting a value in the iframe's src by reading it from the parent page, then passing it as a variable in the php file which will be shown to the user.

Let's say that 
    `$value_from_parent_page = "song1"`

and parent page contains copy-able code for the users
    `<iframe src="http://example.com/load.php?embed='$value_from_parent_page'" ></iframe>`

The load.php contains
    `<?php 
$val  =  $_GET['embed'];
echo "<audio src='"$val".mp3'></audio>";
?>`

The result has to be like
    `<audio src='song1.mp3'></audio>`

Is it possible to work like that and is the code valid? (i apologise I don't have access to normal computer to test).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I want users of my website to externally embed my player to their websites. Is there any better way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This should work, and is valid, now the issue of using an iframe would be well, make sure that it is an iframe you need as there are probably better ways of going about this, but in your scenario i would say this is the best way to do it and valid for best cross platform support.

Comment: I'm sorry i forgot to mention that I want the users of my website to be able to externally embed my player to their websites. Is there any better way to achieve that?

Comment: No this to me would be the proper way of going about it, when you embed a youtube video it looks like this, 

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/njos57IJf-0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

using their mod-rewrite or something similar they are using the same function or an equivlent possibly in asp or something, but there is probably one embed index file and the njos57IJf-0 is telling the server which entries info to select and display